# Questions about several SQL commands

Tags: sql

I am working on my database class project. I am reading the PostgreSQL `Write-ahead-logging` README, it mentioned several commands such as SQL commands

```
BEGIN 
COMMIT 
ROLLBACK 
SAVEPOINT 
ROLLBACK  
RELEASE
```

In the SQL standard, I didn't see those commands. I am confused by that. What's the differences between those commands and standard "SELECT"? Could anyone tell me more about those commands? Can those commands be used the same way as standard SQL?

Comment: Need to learn about transactions.

Comment: The same difference as there is between the "standard SELECT" and "INSERT" or "DELETE" or "UPDATE" - they're totally different things. Please find a SQL tutorial and read the section on transactions, as all of the SQL keywords you mention are related to them.

Comment: All those commands **are** part of the SQL standard. Check the Postgres (btw: *not* PostGre) manual. Each command has a section at the end that documents if the command is standard-compliant or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ANSI SQL Standard [http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt] is also your friend, and you can find these keywords defined there.

Generally all these keywords behave similarly across platforms, but beware the subtle differences in their function, performance or usage.

For example: SAVEPOPINT has similar meanings across different platforms (albeit possibly differing implementations or context), so you need to refer to your platform docs for specifics.

In this case, the Postgres 9.1 manual [http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/] (the one I have bookmarked) ROLLBACK and RELEASE keywords are used together with other modifiers to apply to  a SAVEPOINT within a transaction.

OTOH: T-SQL (MS-SQL Server) requires SAVE|ROLLBACK TRANSACTION when operating on a SAVEPOINT [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx].

Hope that helps!